# How to read in a Java client a response from servlet?

Tags: java, servlets

I have a Java application :

-this application send a String :

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    try {
        HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
        StringEntity params = new StringEntity(xml);
        request.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        request.setEntity(params);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

        // handle response here...
        String res= response.toString();
        System.out.println("RESPONSE=>\n"+response); //where i read the response
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle exception here
    } finally {
        httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
    }
```

I work with this String in my servlet and I just want to send a String response.

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print("TEST");
```

But when i read the response i just have my header:

```
RESPONSE=>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK [X-Powered-By: Servlet/3.0 JSP/2.2 (GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 Java/Oracle Corporation/1.7), Server: GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2, Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8, Content-Length: 83, Date: Fri, 14 Dec 2012 17:17:07 GMT]
```

Someone can help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong method to read your response date. Calling:

```
String res= response.toString();
```

Just gives you the string representation of the Response object, not the data it contains. The Apache Http Commons library has a utility class that makes it easy to read responses, called `EntityUtils`. Use this instead to read the entire response body. Don't forget that you need to verify that the request actually completed successfully before doing this:

```
if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    final String res = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
}
```